# Entity Framework Core - EF Core 2.2 - 'Point.Boundary' is of an interface type ('IGeometry')

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying the new functionality with EF Core 2.2. It is based on the following article. "Announcing Entity Framework Core 2.2"
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2/

I installed the following Nuget package.

[image]

I added the following to my model.

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;


//New as of EF.Core 2.2 
//[Required] 
//[NotMapped] 
public Point Location { get; set; }
```

[image]

During my application startup I get the following error in my Database Context on the following line:
     Database.EnsureCreated();

[image]

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The property 'Point.Boundary' is of an interface type ('IGeometry'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: I am also having this problem. .net core 2.2 with entity framework core 2.2. I get the error when running add-migration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call `UseNetTopologySuite()`. Example here:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opts => opts.UseNetTopologySuite());
    }
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}


public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

I ran into this problem because I had a 
`if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)` around everything in my `OnConfiguring`. I had to remove this in order to get `add-migrations` to work.

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle pointed out you need to call `UseNetTopologySuite()`, but I would call it during ConfigureServices like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
            .AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBConnection"),
                                o=>o.UseNetTopologySuite()))
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```