# ef core 3 preview 3. UseNetTopologySuite requires AddEntityFrameworkSqlServerNetTopologySuite

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using NetTopologySuite(NTS). It is based on the following article: 
[Spatial Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial),
but version of this library is 3.0 preview 3.

Calling `UseNetTopologySuite()` according to the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688803/entity-framework-core-ef-core-2-2-point-boundary-is-of-an-interface-type):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
       .Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
    }
```

But when executing "Add-migration" to add migration, I receive this error:

```
UseNetTopologySuite requires AddEntityFrameworkSqlServerNetTopologySuite to be called on the internal service provider used.
```

These are my project dependencies:

[[image: Project Dependencies]]