# How to use LINQPad with spatial/geometry columns?

Tags: linqpad, ef-core-2.2

I have an EF Core 2.2 project/DBContext with models that have the `Point` data type.

```
   public Point Location { get; set; }
```

When trying to test the connection in LINQPad, I get this error:

> Error Testing EF Core Connection: The property 'Point.Boundary' is of
>   an interface type ('IGeometry'). If it is a navigation property
>   manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to
>   a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the
>   NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

It's not a navigation property, nor can I apply the `NotMappedAttribute`, since it's a vital property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688803/entity-framework-core-ef-core-2-2-point-boundary-is-of-an-interface-type

Could the UseNetTopologySuite method not be firing when instantiated from LINQPad?

Comment: @JoeAlbahari, not really. I have added the dependencies , put the appsettins.json in the LINQPad install. However, LINQPad now says:
Error Testing EF Core Connection: An exception was thrown when trying to open the database connection.
InvalidOperationException - Instance failure.

Testing with a simple Console test app that uses my .NET Std lib with the EF Core database context (and all the TopologySuite thingies), works fine.
What instance is it complaining about? Does LINQPad have a log file?

Comment: It sounds like it's picking up the wrong connection string. Try running this query: this.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString

Comment: Also, are you able to try it in LINQPad 6? The EF support has been substantially upgraded.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari, I tried the latest v6 Beta. Because I do load an appsettings.json file in the OnConfiguring method of the DatabaseContext class, I had to put that in the LINQPad folder. I can now successfully create a connect. However, when I try to run any query , I get 
"FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Users\Magnus\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad6\_biqmcihs\shadow-1\appsettings.json'."